# openbsd httpd php execution

Tags: apache, php, openbsd

I just installed openbsd 56 and want to configure the default Reyk Floeter's httpd server.

Here are the simple steps I followed:

- I installed php-fpm via pkg_add
- I authorized httpd in /etc/rc.conf
- I created a file /var/www/htdocs/index.php
- I started php-fpm and https
- I tested 192.168.xx.xx/index.php

And it worked well. Everything is fine, the php script is well executed and the browser displays the page successfully.

The problem is that I query 192.168.xx.xx/index.php, but if I query just the IP (192.168.xx.xx/), it won't execute the php script and propose to download it instead.

Is there any reason or solution for this ?

FYI, the php-fpm config is the default one. And the httpd config is very basic:

```
ext_addr="egress"
server "default" {
        listen on $ext_addr port 80
        location "*.php" {
                fastcgi socket "/run/php-fpm.sock"
        }
        directory { no auto index, index "index.php" }
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I cannot reproduce this bug, I have 5.6 fully patched. A simple website with php and the configuration you postrd works for me with and without index.php. ¿Did you apply this patch for 5.6? http://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/patches/5.6/common/009_httpd.patch.sig

Comment: You can apply patch for this. and read this https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-apply-updates-on-openbsd-operating-system/ http://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/patches/5.6/common/009_httpd.patch.sig

Answer (score 1):

Previously, serving a FastCGI page as the default index was unsupported. This is fixed in -current.